# Simple Sankey Visualization doesn't work (blank)

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to visualize refugee flow with a sankey diagram using the plotly lib, but all I'm getting is a blank diagram.

I tried to follow https://www.kaggle.com/meetnaren/past-and-current-job-titles-of-data-professionals/ and https://plot.ly/~alishobeiri/1257.embed but it didn't work.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

countries = ['Australia', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Canada', 'China, Hong Kong SAR', 'Denmark', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Italy', 'Luxembourg', 'Morocco', 'Netherlands', 'Norway', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Tunisia', 'Turkey', 'United Kingdom', 'United States of America']

origins = ['Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown', 'Various/Unknown']

values = [180000, 282000, 55000, 168511, 30000, 2000, 290000, 265000, 18000, 26500, 1800, 3000, 14200, 2500, 2000, 44000, 10000, 2000, 2700, 208000, 350000]

colors = ['#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46', '#262C46']


plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
data_trace = dict(
    type='sankey',
    domain = dict(
      x =  [0,1],
      y =  [0,1]
    ),
    orientation = "h",
    valueformat = ".0f",
    node = dict(
      pad = 10,
      thickness = 30,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0
      ),
      label =  values,
      color = colors
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = origins,
      target = countries,
      value = values,
      color = colors
  )
)

layout =  dict(
    title = "Refugee Flow",
    height = 772,
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    ),    
)

fig = dict(data=[data_trace], layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Expected graph. 
Actual result: Blank

Comment: Try to change notebook mode as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560138/plotly-offline-iplot-gives-a-large-blank-field-as-its-output-why/53930462#53930462). Maybe you jupyter notebook didn't allow plotly to use Javascript and that because you got blank cell

Comment: you solved problem with blank result?