# Run Plotly script from command line

Tags: python, bash, plot, command, plotly

I'm trying to run all cells of jupyter notebook from command line. For that task, I have done:

```
jupyter nbconvert --inplace --execute myNotebook.ipynb.
```

The problem now is that my script contains some plots from Plotly library and then when I open the notebook again using jupyter's interface, plots are blanks. I have used many options like:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

%matplotlib inline
```

¿Anyone has any idea for this problem?

Thanks

I add part of my script in order to help you.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40]),'two' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40])})

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.one,y=df.two))
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[min(df.one),max(df.one)])
iplot(fig)

print(datetime.now())
```

Comment: I suspect  --inplace is replacing your existing notebook                                        
 jupyter nbconvert --execute <notebook> or try this jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook <notebook>

Comment: The option  "jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook Untitled.ipynb" creates a new file .ipynb with plots in blank.

The option  "jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook Untitled.ipynb" creates an html file.

I'm going to edit my post for adding part of my script.
Thanks!

Comment: I can see plots I ran your code it works for me

Comment: Have you tried to update de notebook from command line and open again?

Comment: Update? , I just ran the notebook with your command and it works

Comment: Look at the last line of code: print(datetime.now()) This show the datetime now, so, I need to update this notebook everyday updating both the plot and time. However, when I run  "jupyter nbconvert --inplace --execute myNotebook.ipynb" in a terminal, time is updated but not plo t(which is blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with two step

1. Your notebook is not trusted issue exists with plotly so trust your notebook

   `jupyter trust myNotebook.ipynb`
2. Now run your notebook from command line

   `jupyter nbconvert --inplace --execute myNotebook.ipynb.`

You can also have a look at [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560138/plotly-offline-iplot-gives-a-large-blank-field-as-its-output-in-jupyter-notebook)

Here is my working notebook image[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh! Great! Thanks for the information, I finally could run the script corretly.

It is important to mention that in my case I have had to executed the steps backwards. I mean, firstly I have run 

jupyter nbconvert --inplace --execute myNotebook.ipynb

And then:

jupyter trust myNotebook.ipynb

Because when I executed the first command my notebook was converted to not trust authomatically.

Thank you so much!